# {count} of shown/rendered channel entries passed through conditionals

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals

When I display a couple of entries using the channel tag, and use the {count} var inside the entries template, I simply get 1,2,3,4 etc.

When I use a conditional to filter entries like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='artworks'}
    {if "{specifications}{type}{/specifications}" == "Painting"}
        {count}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now I successfully filter my entries to only display those entries that match my criteria, however, my count var renders as (eg) 4,8.

I would like to have a variable that renders as 1,2,3 etc.
So the count var should only count the rendered entries.

Ho to get this to work?

Comment: What kind of fieldtype is `{specifications}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really *filtering* your entries - you're simply showing some content conditionally. Filtering would happen at the query level - if `specifications` were a Grid field, then you could do:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='artworks' search:specifications="Painting"}
```

Then `{count}` would work as you expected.

But if `specifications` is a Relationship field, this won't work. You'll need to resort to some PHP (which will need to be [enabled for this specific template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/edit_template.html#allow-php)).

```
<?php $count = 1; ?>
{exp:channel:entries channel='artworks'}
    {if "{specifications}{type}{/specifications}" == "Painting"}
        <?php echo $count; $count++; ?>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I actually didn't need to use your php method. search:specifications="Painting" was sufficient. Specifications is a Matrix field containing (among others) a select dropdown containing "Painting, Sketch, Study etc"